# SwiftUI sort list by job hierarchy

Tags: sorting, listview, arraylist, swiftui

I am trying to sort my array by job hierarchy.

for example I have model:

```
struct Employee{

   let name: String
   let job: String
   let phone: String
   let mail: Sting
}
```

And then I have employees

```
class EmployeeViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var employees: [Employee] = [
        Employee(name: "John", job: "Manager", age: 32),
        Employee(name: "Anna", job: "CEO", age: 40),
        Employee(name: "Julia", job: "Junior Developer", age: 25),
        Employee(name: "Kevin", job: "Senior Developer", age: 29)
        
    ]  
}
```

I would like to sort them to the list like this:

```
CEO Anna
Manager John
Kevin Senior Developer
Julia Junior Developer
```

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Employee` struct and your `EmployeeViewModel.employees` didn't match, so I changed `Employee` to conform. In order to make it sortable, `Employee` has to conform to the `Comparable` protocol. Since you wanted a set job order, the easiest way was to use an `enum` to rank them. Also, `Employee` should conform to the `Identifiable` protocol to use them in a `ForEach` for display purposes. You can cheat a bit, but eventually you will need to conform, so make it a habit from the beginning.

```
struct SortByJob: View {
    @StateObject var employeeVM = EmployeeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(employeeVM.employees.sorted()) { employee in
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    Text(employee.job.description)
                    Text(employee.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Employee: Identifiable, Comparable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let job: Job
    let age: Int
    
    static func < (lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Bool {
        lhs.job.rawValue < rhs.job.rawValue
    }
}

enum Job: Int {
    case ceo = 1
    case manager = 2
    case seniorDeveloper = 3
    case juniorDeveloper = 4
    
    // This allows you to return a String from the enum for display purposes.
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .ceo:
            return "CEO"
        case .manager:
            return "Manager"
        case .seniorDeveloper:
            return "Senior Developer"
        case .juniorDeveloper:
            return "Junior Developer"
        }
    }
}
```